# Can't get 100% height on Section

Tags: html, css

Here is my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/KfjGU/425/

The code is pretty simple:

```
    <main>
        <section class="parallax">

        </section>



        <section class="content">
            <h1>Center</h1>      
        </section>
    </main>
```

and in the css, set

```
 html, body { min-height: 100%; }
```

and the same with the section with the specific class parallax:

```
 .parallax { height: 100%; }
```

Would appreciate any help here.

Kind regards,

George

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting `main` to `100%`. If you don't set it to `100%`, it'll be `0%` since it doesn't know what to set it to.

```
html, body, main, .parallax {
    height: 100% !important;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/KfjGU/426/) a demo

Comment: Like he said. What you are doing in your code LoveAndHappiness is, you are setting a height of 100% WITHIN the "main" tag, and since the main tag is not 100% of the website the div in it can not expand over the height of main. First set main to 100% so it goes all the way to the bottom, and then you can set your section to 100%. Good answer Idris.

Comment: A thorough and concise explanation. Nice. @LittleB0Y

Comment: Thank you, edited it so it makes more sense lol. Good example above. Point for u.

Comment: you could also work with `height: inherit`. Of course the result will be the same, just depends how you write you CSS

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `main` to the height of 100% because it is a new tag that you create and therefore has no properties. Thus `.parralax` will be `100%` of an undefined height, hence nothing is working.